# Простое или составное глагольное сказуемое?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в предложении "Не давайте отдыхать ему". Сказуемое "не давайте" (простое, а петь-дополнение) или "не давайте отдыхать" (составное глагольное или  это в повелительном наклонении). Запуталась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Не давайте отдыхать ему.***

Не давайте (что?) отдыхать. Здесь инфинитив в роли дополнения. Значение: не разрешайте, не позволяйте, не предоставляйте возможности.

**Сказуемое простое глагольное.** Составное глагольное сказуемое тоже включает модальную связку (нельзя отдыхать), но инфинитив относится к субъекту действия (в заданном предложении он относится к другому лицу).

Также существует **частица** ДАВАЙ, ДАВАЙТЕ, которая используется для образования **повелительного наклонения**: давай играть, давай поиграем (предложение совместного действия).

Из словаря Кузнецова

ДАТЬ, св. 1. (кому-чему) кого-что. Передать из рук в руки; вручить. Д. денег на дорогу. 2. (кому-чему) кого-что. **Предоставить что-л.; обеспечить кому-л., что-л., сделать возможным для кого-л.** Д. квартиру.  **Дайте пройти!** (резкое требование пропустить, позволить пройти).

Из словаря Ожегова

ДАТЬ, сов. 1. кого-что кому. То же, что вручить (в 1 знач.). Д. деньги. Д. книгу. 2. **что или с неопр. кому.** То же, что **предоставить.** Д. помещение. Д. работу. Д. место. **Д. возможность что-н. делать**. Д. покой. Д. пить. **Не дали спать всю ночь.**

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё понятно